# The process by which Middle English developed... or WAS developed?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

From [an answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-native-English-speakers-often-use-phrasal-verbs/answer/Coba-Weel):

> "...the phrasal verbs are usually Germanic, and Germanic words in
>   English are more often colloquial, whereas Romance words are more
>   often formal. The colloquial/formal distinction (linguists speak of
>   colloquial and formal registers) traces its origin, or so I have heard
>   it theorized, to the process by which Middle English developed out of
>   peasant Anglo-Saxon and elite Norman French."

To my understanding, according to this sentence, Middle English was affected by the process so is passive. If so why doesn't this sentence have a "was" in it? I mean isn't **"the process by which Middle English WAS developed..."** the correct one? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: No one did the development. ME evolved on its own. The sentence does **not** suggest passivity. Rather than being "affected by the process," it states clearly that the development **was** the process.

Comment: Please cite the source of the statement.

Comment: Ally, I added the link, and also the preceding sentence in the quote (since this provides important context for the sentence you're asking about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion between an *intransitive verb* (which doesn't have a passive form) and a *transitive verb* (which can be active or passive) is one that has been responsible for many incorrect passive-shaming accusations.

It doesn't help that English has many verbs that can act as transitive verbs or intransitive verbs - they are *ambitransitive*. Just like *develop* here:

> Middle English developed out of XYZ

The above is an intransitive verb with extra prepositions that add more detail.

> ABC developed Middle English.

This is a transitive verb in the active voice, with the *agent* as the subject and the *patient* as the object.

> Middle English was developed by ABC.

This is a transitive verb in the passive voice, with *by* indicating the *agent* of the action and the *patient* of the action being the subject. This is the "classic" transformation of the active into the passive in English.

> Middle English was developed out of / from XYZ.

This is a transitive verb in the passive voice, with extra prepositions to attach itself to an argument.

So why in this case is the author using an intransitive verb instead of a transitive verb in the passive voice? Because the author wants to focus solely on the subject "Middle English" as an *experiencer* of the action, rather than making it a *patient* which would imply some kind of *agent* deliberately developing Middle English.

Comment: In summary, [see my comment at OP].

Comment: @Kris If you feel that a comment of yours is a useful summary of this answer, perhaps you should include its actual text here.

Comment: This is a comprehensive answer, so I'm not sure why you got the driveby downvote. Maybe someone didn't understand the key point you were making about *agency*. +1, and welcome to EL&U :-)

Comment: @Michaelyus thank you so much for your wonderful explanation but I'm confused about one thing: Why did author use "by which" phrase while "developed" is being used as an intransitive verb in this sentence. Can you explain it ? Thank you.

Comment: @AllyFe Compare: _Something occurred because of reason X_ and _X is the reason because of which something occurred_. This latter sentence contains a relative clause introduced by a preposition, which requires _because of which_. Same thing with your example.